# Assistance With Cryptogram Guessing Game Python

Tags: python-3.x

Hey I have an issue with the program I have been set to do. We were set to do a cryptogram guessing game and I've done 90% but this part I just can't get past. When you run the program you can log in then you can have your sentece encrypted and you choose 2 "giveaway letters". They are then uncovered and you can inpu the letter and the number you think that corresponds with the letter. The first time it works and the second time it doesn't work, you can input the letters and numbers all you like but it just wont replace it. When you run the program you'll understand.

````py
#Modules

import random 
import time

#Variables

encrypted = ""
esentence = ""
sentence = ""
val = "False"
letterinp = ""

#Login Variables

tu = "teacher123"
tp = "admin321"

su = "student1"
sp = "password321"

loggedin = "False"
login = ""

#Functions

#Clears The Terminal
def clr():
    print("\n"*40)

#Prints Out Encryption Table
def table():
    for i in range(26):
        print(a[i], "=", n[i])

#Prints Main Game

def main():

    for i in a:

        print(i+"  ", end = " ")
    print("\n")

    print("")
    print("")
    for i in a:

        x = a.index(i)

        if i in give1:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in give2:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in letterinp:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        else:
            print("__ ",end = " ")

    print("\n\n############################################################################")
    print (sentence.center(76))
    print("############################################################################\n")

    print(encrypted)

    for i in sentence:

        x2 = sentence.index(i)

        if i in give1:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in give2:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in letterinp:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i == " ":
            print("  ", end = " ")
        else:
            print("__",end = " ")       

def main2():

    print("\n\n\nEnter The Letter")
    letterinp = input()
    indexa = a.index(letterinp)

    print("Enter The Number")
    numberinp = input()
    indexn = n.index(numberinp)

    if indexa == indexn:
        if letterinp in sentence:
            main()



#Lists

a=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
n = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26']
random.shuffle(n)

print("Welcome To The Cryptogram Game")
time.sleep(0.2)
print("For helping purposes please login using 'teacher123' and 'admin321'\n then input 2 and input for exaple 'hello world'\n then input 'h' and 'w' (as the giveaway letters)\n and then input the the letter corresponding to the number.\n It will work once, it will uncover the hidden letter but when you try to uncover the next one it simply removes the last change and replaces the letter\n but the last one isn't replaced anymore.\n Run the program and you will understand.")
time.sleep(2)
print("\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n")


while loggedin == "False":

    print("Please Enter Your Username")
    username = input(">")


    if username == tu:
        print("\nEnter Your Password")
        password = input(">")

        if password == tp:
            print("\nWelcome Teacher User")
            login = "teacher"
            loggedin = "True"
        else:
            print("\nIncorrect Username Or Password")


    elif username == su:
        print("\nEnter Your Password")
        password = input(">")

        if password == sp:
            print("\nWelcome Student User")
            login = "student"
            loggedin = "True"

        else:
            print("\nIncorrect Username Or Password")


    else:
        print("\nUser Not Registered")
        print("Registration is currently closed\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)

#Main Program

if login == "teacher":
    while val == "False":

        #Lets user chose between auto encryption and manual
        print("""You Can
1. Type the phrase using the encryption table
2. Have your phrase automatically encrypted""")

        #Lets user input their option
        menu1 = input(">")

        if menu1 == "1":

            print("What sentence do you want to encrypt?")
            sentence = input(">")
            table()
            print("Type end to stop adding letters to the sentence")


            while esentence != "end":
                print("Print the phrase using the encryption table using the numbers")
                esentence = input(">")
                encrypted += esentence + " "
                encrypted = encrypted.replace("end","")

            val = "True"

        elif menu1 == "2":
            print("Type the phrase you would like to have encrypted")
            sentence = input(">").lower()

            clr()

            for char in sentence:
                if char in a:
                    encrypted += (n[a.index(char)] + ' ').ljust(3)
                else:
                    encrypted += char.ljust(3) 

            val = "True"

        else:
            print("\nThat's Not A Valid Option\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)

elif login == "student":
    print("Becasue you do not have teacher privileges")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You will have a random sentence encrypted for you")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("\nGood Luck!\n")

    lines = open('wordlist.txt').read().splitlines()
    sentence = random.choice(lines)

    for char in sentence:
        if char in a:
            encrypted += (n[a.index(char)] + ' ').ljust(3)
        else:
            encrypted += char.ljust(3) 

print("Enter the first giveaway letter")
give1 = input(">").lower()
print("Enter the second giveaway letter")
give2 = input(">").lower()


while True:
    for i in a:

        print(i+"  ", end = " ")

    print("")
    print("")
    for i in a:

        x = a.index(i)

        if i in give1:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i == give2:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        else:
            print("__ ",end = " ")


    print("\n\n############################################################################")
    print (sentence.center(76))
    print("############################################################################\n")

    print(encrypted)

    for i in sentence:

        x2 = sentence.index(i)

        if i in give1:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in give2:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in letterinp:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i == " ":
            print("  ", end = " ")
        else:
            print("__",end = " ")


    print("\nEnter The Letter")
    letterinp = input()
    indexa = a.index(letterinp)

    print("Enter The Number")
    numberinp = input()
    indexn = n.index(numberinp)

while True:
    main()
    main2()```
````

Comment: Most of it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

```py
#sentence = input()
sentencelist = list(sentence)

while " " in sentencelist:
    sentencelist.remove(" ")

sentencelist = list(dict.fromkeys(sentencelist))
print(mylist)

maxguesses = len(sentencelist)

if guesses == maxguesses: #Make guesses variable in program after if statments
    print("Well Done! You Have Solved The Puzzle")
else:
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all of it is done.

```py
#Modules.

import random 
import time

#Variables.

encrypted = ""
esentence = ""
sentence = ""
val = "False"
letterinp = ""
guesses = 0
maxguesses = 0
givelenloop = False
sentencevalidation = False

#Login Variables.

tu = "teacher123"
tp = "admin321"

su = "student1"
sp = "password321"

loggedin = "False"
login = ""

#Lists

a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
n = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26']
g = []

#Shuffles the number list to make the encryption random everytime.
random.shuffle(n)

#Functions.

#Clears The Terminal.
def clr():
    print("\n"*40)


#Prints Out Encryption Table.
def table():
    for i in range(26):
        print(a[i], "=", n[i])


#Prints Main Game.

def main():

    #Clears the screen to make the program look cleaner.
    clr()

    #For all the letters in the alphabet(26).
    for i in a:

        #Prints the all letters in the alphabet with two spaces between them.
        print(i+"  ", end = " ")

    #Prints two blank lines to stop the program from looking horrible.
    print("")
    print("")

    #For all the letters in the alphabet(26).
    for i in a:

        #Finds the position of i in the alphabet
        x = a.index(i)

        #If i is in give1.
        if i in give1:
            #Replaces the underscore with give1.
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")

        #If i is in give2.    
        elif i in give2:
            #Replaces the underscore with give2.
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")

        #If i is in the list g.    
        elif i in g:
            #Replaces the underscore with the letter(s) in g.
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")

        #If there is nothing else to replace. The blank spaces will be replaced by two underscores.    
        else:
            print("__ ",end = " ")


    print("\n\n############################################################################")
    print (sentence.center(76))
    print("############################################################################\n")


    print(encrypted)

    for i in sentence:

        x2 = sentence.index(i)

        if i in give1:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in give2:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in g:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i == " ":
            print("  ", end = " ")
        else:
            print("__",end = " ")


def main2():

    print("\n\n\nEnter The Letter")
    letterinp = input()
    indexa = a.index(letterinp)

    print("Enter The Number")
    numberinp = input()
    indexn = n.index(numberinp)

    if indexa == indexn:
        g.append(letterinp)
        guesses = guesses + 1
        main()

def sen2list():
    sentencelist = list(sentence)    
    while " " in sentencelist:
        sentencelist.remove(" ")    
    sentencelist = list(dict.fromkeys(sentencelist))
    maxguesses = len(sentencelist)


print("Welcome To The Cryptogram Game")


while loggedin == "False":

    print("Please Enter Your Username")
    username = input(">")


    if username == tu:
        print("\nEnter Your Password")
        password = input(">")

        if password == tp:
            print("\nWelcome Teacher User")
            login = "teacher"
            loggedin = "True"
        else:
            print("\nIncorrect Username Or Password")


    elif username == su:
        print("\nEnter Your Password")
        password = input(">")

        if password == sp:
            print("\nWelcome Student User")
            login = "student"
            loggedin = "True"

        else:
            print("\nIncorrect Username Or Password")


    else:
        print("\nUser Not Registered")
        print("Registration is currently closed\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)

#Main Program

if login == "teacher":
    while val == "False":

        #Lets user chose between auto encryption and manual
        print("""You Can
1. Type the phrase using the encryption table
2. Have your phrase automatically encrypted""")

        #Lets user input their option
        menu1 = input(">")

        if menu1 == "1":
            print("Please enter the name of the puzzle.")
            puzzlename = input(">")
            print("What sentence do you want to encrypt?")
            print("Please only use letters and don't use numbers as the program will break.")
            sentence = input(">").lower()
            sent2list()
            table()
            print("Type end to stop adding letters to the sentence")


            while esentence != "end":
                print("Print the phrase using the encryption table using the numbers")
                print("Please only input numbers and not letters as it will break the program.")
                esentence = input(">")
                encrypted += esentence + " "
                encrypted = encrypted.replace("end","")

            val = "True"

        elif menu1 == "2":
            print("Please enter the name of the puzzle.")
            puzzlename = input(">")

            while sentencevalidation == False:
                print("Type the phrase you would like to have encrypted")
                print("Please only use letters and don't use numbers as the program will ignore them.")
                sentence = input(">").lower()

                #if any(char.isdigit() for char in sentence):
                    #sentence = ''.join([i for i in sentence if not i.isdigit()])
                #else:
                    #sen2list()

                #clr()
                for char in sentence:
                    if char not in a:
                        print("You can only input letters")
                        sentencevalidation = False

                    else:
                        sentencevalidation = True



                for char in sentence:
                    if char in a:
                        encrypted += (n[a.index(char)] + ' ').ljust(3)
                    else:
                        encrypted += char.ljust(3)


            val = "True"

        else:
            print("\nThat's Not A Valid Option\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)

elif login == "student":
    print("Becasue you do not have teacher privileges")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You will have a random sentence encrypted for you")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("\nGood Luck!\n")
    print("However, you can still enter the name of the puzzle.")
    puzzlename = input(">")

    lines = open('wordlist.txt').read().splitlines()
    sentence = random.choice(lines)

    for char in sentence:
        if char in a:
            encrypted += (n[a.index(char)] + ' ').ljust(3)
        else:
            encrypted += char.ljust(3) 

while givelenloop == False:
    print("Enter the first giveaway letter")
    print("If you enter numbers they will be ignored by the program")
    give1 = input(">").lower()
    give1len = len(give1)

    print("Enter the second giveaway letter")
    print("If you enter numbers they will be ignored by the program")
    give2 = input(">").lower()
    give2len = len(give2)

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in give1):
        give1 = ''.join([i for i in give1 if not i.isdigit()])

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in give2):
        give2 = ''.join([i for i in give2 if not i.isdigit()])

    if give1len >1 or give2len > 1:
        print("Please input only one letter per giveaway letter!\n")

    else:
        givelenloop = True


sen2list()

if give1 in sentence:
    guesses += 1

if give2 in sentence:
    guesses += 1


while guesses != maxguesses:

    clr()

    for i in a:

        print(i+"  ", end = " ")

    print("")
    print("")
    for i in a:

        x = a.index(i)

        if i in give1:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in give2:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in g:
            print(str(n[x]) + " ", end = " ")
        else:
            print("__ ",end = " ")


    print("\n\n############################################################################")
    print (sentence.center(76))
    print("############################################################################\n")

    print(encrypted)

    for i in sentence:

        x2 = sentence.index(i)

        if i in give1:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in give2:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i in g:
            print(str(sentence[x2]) + " ", end = " ")
        elif i == " ":
            print("  ", end = " ")
        else:
            print("__",end = " ")


    print("\nEnter The Letter")
    letterinp = input()
    indexa = a.index(letterinp)

    print("Enter The Number")
    numberinp = input()
    indexn = n.index(numberinp)

    if indexa == indexn:
        g.append(letterinp)
        guesses = guesses + 1

main()
time.sleep(2)
clr()
print("Well Done!")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("You Have Solved The " + puzzlename + " Puzzle!")
```